# What are the access times for different GPU memory spaces?

Tags: performance, caching, gpu, nvidia, gpgpu

This is a question about discrete GPUs, mostly recent GPUs (NVIDIA Kepler, Maxwell; and whatever's in AMD Kaveri and R290's).

How much does it take to load an otherwise-uncached element into a register from...

- Global device memory?
- Global memory L2 cache?
- Texture cache(s)?
- Constant cache(s)?
- Per-core L1 cache?
- (Per-core shared memory - should be the same as L1 cache.)

A link to a table somewhere would be great, an explanation would be ok...

Answer (score 3):

It varies on gpu, generation, how its integrated(like pcie) and other things. 
I work with ASM often and these are numbers that I work with:

-Global device memory? around 300-800 clocks. (motherboard mounted GPUs like laptops that use main memory have slower memory)

-Global memory L2 cache? around 100 clock cycles

-Texture cache(s)? guessing 50-100 clock cycles

-Constant cache(s)? around 1-3 clock cycles if it is in the cache or else L2 cache (~50-100 clocks) or even global mem 300-500 clocks. (depending on if it is a cache hit or miss)

-Per-core (i.e. Per-SMX/SMM in Kepler/Maxwell) L1 cache? around 1-3 clock cycles

-Per-core (i.e. Per-SMX/SMM in Kepler/Maxwell) shared memory?  around 1-3 clock cycles

I also did some online searches to see how close I was and found this. The numbers are different then mine. http://lpgpu.org/wp/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/poster_andresch_acaces2014.pdf  I think the actual time it takes vs what the programmer should be working with are two different numbers because of the multi-threading. Hope this helps.

Comment: Is L2 cache really that horrible? that's not even an order-of-magnitude faster...

Comment: Also, that link is really weird. Does addition really take 6 clock cycles on a GPU? I would have thought it was, well, just 1.

Comment: Back in 2011 I (and others) did some L2 benchmarking (https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/496975/fermi-l2-cache-how-fast-is-the-l2-cache-how-do-i-access-it-/?offset=9) and back then global was 800-1000 and L2 was around 200. So I'm guessing L2 improved liked global did so maybe around 100 cycles.  This might not be that accurate.

Comment: There are two kinds of latencies. First there is the real actual latency. This is actually how long the hardware takes. Then there is the latency that a programmer is concerned about.  This latency is more of a opinion/guess and depends occupancy (# of warps(NVidia) or wavefronts(AMD)). Since the GPU can do other things while waiting, the amount of time is less. L1, constant(, and shared are essentially free.  L2 is usually free but not always and global usually has a time hit.  In the above timings, L1, Constant, and shared are in "Programmers time" and global and L2 are in "actual time".